# How does numpy.unique eliminate duplicate columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I cannot understand correctly how Numpy's `unique` function works on multi-dimensional arrays. More precisely, I cannot comprehend how the documentation of `unique` describes its operation using the `axis` parameter:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

> When an axis is specified the subarrays indexed by the axis are
> sorted. **This is done by making the specified axis the first dimension
> of the array (move the axis to the first dimension to keep the order
> of the other axes)** and then flattening the subarrays in C order. The
> flattened subarrays are then viewed as a structured type with each
> element given a label, with the effect that we end up with a 1-D array
> of structured types that can be treated in the same way as any other
> 1-D array. The result is that the flattened subarrays are sorted in
> lexicographic order starting with the first element.

I have read multiple times the above-mentioned paragraph but unfortunately I have not managed to get a clear picture of the process, particularly what I have put above in bold. For example, let's say, we have the following 2-D array:

```
import numpy as np

myarray = np.array(
    [
        [ 1,  3,  7,  8,  3], 
        [-5,  0,  9,  2,  0], 
        [10, 11, 12, 85, 11]
    ]
)
```

As you can see, the 2nd and 5th columns containing the values `{3, 0, 11}` are duplicates. If I want to remove duplicate columns by using `numpy.unique` then I run the following:

```
np.unique(myarray, axis=1)
```

Which provides the expected result:

```
array([[ 1,  3,  7,  8],
       [-5,  0,  9,  2],
       [10, 11, 12, 85]])
```

The 5th column was indeed removed as expected given that it was a duplicate (of the 2nd column). So visually, the result is understandable. However if I read the above-mentioned documentation, trying to move the selected axis as the first dimension of the array as suggested, and then flattening the resulted subarrays, I cannot understand how exactly Numpy splitted and reorganized the structure of the array to arrive to the final result.

Could you kindly provide a step by step presentation based on the above-mentioned documentation describing how Numpy arrives at this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code link is found on the docs page

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L138-L320

The basic steps are:

Move the axis to the start:

```
In [103]: ar = np.moveaxis(myarray, 1, 0)
```

Make a contiguous 2d array:

```
In [104]: orig_shape, orig_dtype = ar.shape, ar.dtype
     ...: ar = ar.reshape(orig_shape[0], np.prod(orig_shape[1:], dtype=np.intp))
     ...: ar = np.ascontiguousarray(ar)    
In [105]: ar
Out[105]: 
array([[ 1, -5, 10],
       [ 3,  0, 11],
       [ 7,  9, 12],
       [ 8,  2, 85],
       [ 3,  0, 11]])
```

Define a composite dtype, and make a structured array from that:

```
In [106]: dtype = [('f{i}'.format(i=i), ar.dtype) for i in range(ar.shape[1])];dtype
Out[106]: [('f0', dtype('int32')), ('f1', dtype('int32')), ('f2', dtype('int32'))]

In [107]: consolidated = ar.view(dtype); consolidated
Out[107]: 
array([[(1, -5, 10)],
       [(3,  0, 11)],
       [(7,  9, 12)],
       [(8,  2, 85)],
       [(3,  0, 11)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

That array can then be treated as a 1d array:

```
In [108]: np.lib.arraysetops._unique1d(consolidated)
Out[108]: 
(array([(1, -5, 10), (3,  0, 11), (7,  9, 12), (8,  2, 85)],
       dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')]),)
```

There's further code to reshape this 'unique' array back to the orginal dtype and shape.

Key to the `unique1d` is to sort the array (stripping off the size 1 trailing dimension):

```
In [109]: np.sort(consolidated[:,0])
Out[109]: 
array([(1, -5, 10), (3,  0, 11), (3,  0, 11), (7,  9, 12), (8,  2, 85)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

And then looking for adjacent duplicates.

So the main 'tricky' step is constructing a structured array view that can be sorted as a 1d array.  That sorting is lexographic - first field, then the second etc.

Sorting on the string format of each row gives similar results - but the structured array version is more general

```
In [121]: x=[f'{row}' for row in ar];x
Out[121]: ['[ 1 -5 10]', '[ 3  0 11]', '[ 7  9 12]', '[ 8  2 85]', '[ 3  0 11]']

In [122]: x.sort();x
Out[122]: ['[ 1 -5 10]', '[ 3  0 11]', '[ 3  0 11]', '[ 7  9 12]', '[ 8  2 85]']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your description.

Answer (score 2):

Axis Specified: 1. This means we're focusing on the array column-wise for identifying unique columns.

```
# Conceptual representation, not an actual operation here
# Each column is considered as a single item:
[
 [ 1, -5, 10],
 [ 3,  0, 11],
 [ 7,  9, 12],
 [ 8,  2, 85],
 [ 3,  0, 11]  # Duplicate of the second column
]
```

- Here, NumPy essentially views each column as a structured array element, meaning it looks at the column in its entirety rather than individual elements within it.
- NumPy sorts these "structured types" (our columns) in lexicographical order to efficiently find duplicates. It's like comparing strings: [1, -5, 10] is different from [3, 0, 11], but it notices [3, 0, 11] appears twice :

```
 - "1,-5,10"
 - "3,0,11"
 - "7,9,12"
 - "8,2,85"
 - "3,0,11"  # This is a duplicate when viewed as a "string"
```

After numpy.unique operates on the array with axis=1, you get:

```
array([[ 1,  3,  7,  8],
       [-5,  0,  9,  2],
       [10, 11, 12, 85]])
```